# Vue component cannot read property

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

1. Press button to send request to server
2. server sends a json array in response.
3. I want to show the data on the screen using v-for and component
4. I get the data well, but when I show it on the screen, I get an error.

Error : *Property or method "data" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.*

Why doesn't he recognize "data"?

---

**html**

```html
<template id="dataTemplate">
    <div>
        <p v-for="data in dataList">
            <h3><a :href="data.href">{{ data.title }}></a></h3>
            <p>Date : {{ data.propose_dt }}</p>
        </p>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Vue.component('data-template', {
        template: '#dataTemplate',
        props: ['dataList']
    })
</script>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <data-template :dataList="dataDetail" v-if="dataDetail.length != 0"></data-template>
    </div>
</body>
```

**vue javascript**

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        dataDetail: []
    },
    methods: {
        getData: function() {
            this.searching = true;
            axios.get(url)
            .then(res => {
                this.dataDetail = json array data;
                console.log(this.dataDetil);  //'dataDetail' have right value after server request
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you use `p` tag instead of `div` (if you use ide the ide sholud warn you about that)
just change it to

```
<div v-for="data in dataList">
     <h3><a :href="data.href">{{ data.title }}></a></h3>
     <p>Date : {{ data.propose_dt }}</p>
</div>
```